# Ubuntu 19.10 internal error. Random logouts

Tags: permissions, 19.10

I'm new to using Linux (Ubuntu) as my daily system on my Dell XPS 15.
Since today I keep getting these errors and my user has crashed 3 times today randomly signing me out.

[image: Screenshot From the logs from the random signing out crash]

This is the error I have multiple times a day: (idk if it has something to do with the crashes)

[image: Screenshot from internal error]

This is what `ls -al /var/crash` gives me:

```
total 10888
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Mar 17 18:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Oct 17 14:34 ..
-rw-r-----  1 root whoopsie 11135374 Mar 17 13:50 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 root whoopsie  0 Mar 17 18:17 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie       37 Mar 18 14:24 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.uploaded
```

I also read other people have it after the update from yesterday.

Comment: My guess Xorg is crashing by this error mentioned by report and is automatically started again leading to a "logout" - at least thats happening on my Mint-OS when killing Xorg. Have you tried reinstalling Ubuntu? Did you add special / proprietary driver? Or missing functionality cause of missing driver like WIFI etc?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`.